# Keyup and Focus doesn't work right for different span - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, keyup

**The first problem** in this code is that when I type a number of nights, it doesn't calculate the right output price for Paris and Tokyo, just only for New York.

**The second problem** I want to solve is that a user must submit the number and click the button, after then it must appear in right section. Now when I click the submit button, all offers are closing. Thanks for help.

```js
//// hide offer before the Dom is loaded
//$('ul').hide()
$(document).ready(function() {   
    
    function showHideOffer() {
        $('ul').slideToggle();
    }
    
    //click to show offers
    $('.card').on('click', '.showOffers', showHideOffer, function() {
        $(this).text($(this).text() === 'Hide Offers' ? "Show Offers" : "Hide Offers");
    });
    
    //click to hide offers - change name to show offers doesn't work!!
    $('.card').on('click','.showOffers', showHideOffer);
    
    // click to book, to show info and close button and span
   $('li').on('click', 'button', function(){
      var offerName = $(this).closest('.tour').data('name');
      var offerPrice = $(this).closest('.tour').data('price')
      var message = $('<ol class="breadcrumb"><li class="breadcrumb-item active" style="color:#3CB371">Success! You have booked '+offerName+' offer for '+offerPrice+'!</li></ol>');
       $(this).closest('.tour').append(message);
       
       $(this).prev().closest('.details').remove();
       $(this).remove();        
       $('li').unbind("click");
   });
    
    // filter new offers by clicking a "new" button
    $('#buttons').on('click','.filterNew', function() {
            $('.tour').filter('.newOffer').addClass('highlightnew');
            $('.highlightpopular').removeClass('highlightpopular');
                $('#buttons').on('click', '.filterNew', function() {
                    $('.highlightnew').removeClass('highlightnew');
                });
        });
    
        // filter by popular offers
        $('#buttons').on('click', '.filterPopular', function() { 
            $('.tour').filter('.popular').addClass('highlightpopular');
            $('.highlightnew').removeClass('highlightnew');
        });
    
    // input for number nights
    $('.numberNights').on('keyup', function() {
       var numberNights = +$(this).val(); 
       var priceOffer = +$('li').closest('.tour').data('price');
        
        $('#numberPriceOffer').text(numberNights * priceOffer);
        $('li').find('#numberNightsOffer').text(numberNights);
        $('.numberNights').on('focus', function() {
           $('.numberNights').val(7); 
        });
    });
    
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>GuidedTours</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wageup.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
          .selected {
            color: red;
          }
          .highlightnew {
            background: #3D9970;
          }
            .highlightpopular {
                background: #39CCCC;
            }
            ul {
                display:none;
            }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
       <h2>Guided Tours</h2>
            <hr>
            <div id="tours" class="card">
                <!-- click to show -->
                <button type="button" value="Show Offers" class="btn showOffers btn-primary btn-sm">Show Offers</button>
                
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="usa tour newOffer list-group-item"; data-name="New York" data-price="550">
                  <h3>New York, USA</h3>
                    
                    <span class="details badge badge-success">$<span id="numberPriceOffer">1,899</span> for 
                    <span id="numberNightsOffer">7</span> nights</span>
                    
                  <button class="book btn btn-primary">Book Now</button>
                </li>

                <li class="europe tour newOffer list-group-item" data-name="Paris" data-price="450">
                  <h3>Paris, France</h3>
                    <span class="details badge badge-success">$<span id="numberPriceOffer">2,299</span> for 
                    <span id="numberNightsOffer">7</span> nights</span>
                    
                  <button class="book btn btn-primary">Book Now</button>
                </li>

                <li class="asia tour popular list-group-item" data-name="Tokyo" data-price="650">
                  <h3>Tokyo, Japan</h3>
                  <span class="details badge badge-success">$<span id="numberPriceOffer">3,799</span> for 
                    <span id="numberNightsOffer">7</span> nights</span>
                  <button class="book btn btn-primary">Book Now</button>
                </li>
              </ul>
                <ul id="buttons" class="list-group list list-group-flush">
                <button class="filterNew btn btn-info">New</button>
                <button class="filterPopular btn btn-info">Popular</button>
                </ul>
            </div>
        
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Number of nights</label>
                <input type="nights" class="numberNights form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter a number">
                
              </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>
            </form> 
        </div>





        <!-- Scripts -->

        <!-- Jquery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="guidedtours.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solving the only first problem, the issue is that you are using the same `id` for all the offer prizes due to which it is updating correctly for the first `id` found. Instead of that you need to loop over all the `li` and update all the prices `separately`. Even in your code you are fetching the multiplier only once `var priceOffer = +$('li').closest('.tour').data('price');`

check the `// input for number nights` for the updated code

```js
    //// hide offer before the Dom is loaded
//$('ul').hide()
$(document).ready(function() {   
    
    function showHideOffer() {
        $('ul').slideToggle();
    }
    
    //click to show offers
    $('.card').on('click', '.showOffers', showHideOffer, function() {
        $(this).text($(this).text() === 'Hide Offers' ? "Show Offers" : "Hide Offers");
    });
    
    //click to hide offers - change name to show offers doesn't work!!
    $('.card').on('click','.showOffers', showHideOffer);
    
    // click to book, to show info and close button and span
   $('li').on('click', 'button', function(){
      var offerName = $(this).closest('.tour').data('name');
      var offerPrice = $(this).closest('.tour').data('price')
      var message = $('<ol class="breadcrumb"><li class="breadcrumb-item active" style="color:#3CB371">Success! You have booked '+offerName+' offer for '+offerPrice+'!</li></ol>');
       $(this).closest('.tour').append(message);
       
       $(this).prev().closest('.details').remove();
       $(this).remove();        
       $('li').unbind("click");
   });
    
    // filter new offers by clicking a "new" button
    $('#buttons').on('click','.filterNew', function() {
            $('.tour').filter('.newOffer').addClass('highlightnew');
            $('.highlightpopular').removeClass('highlightpopular');
                $('#buttons').on('click', '.filterNew', function() {
                    $('.highlightnew').removeClass('highlightnew');
                });
        });
    
        // filter by popular offers
        $('#buttons').on('click', '.filterPopular', function() { 
            $('.tour').filter('.popular').addClass('highlightpopular');
            $('.highlightnew').removeClass('highlightnew');
        });
    
    // input for number nights
    $('.numberNights').on('keyup', function() {
       var numberNights = +$(this).val(); 
       $('.offer').find('li').each(function(){
       var priceOffer = $(this).closest('.tour').data('price');
        $(this).find('#numberPriceOffer').text(numberNights * priceOffer);
        $(this).find('#numberNightsOffer').text(numberNights);
        });
        $('.numberNights').on('focus', function() {
           $('.numberNights').val(7); 
        });
    });
    
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>GuidedTours</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wageup.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
          .selected {
            color: red;
          }
          .highlightnew {
            background: #3D9970;
          }
            .highlightpopular {
                background: #39CCCC;
            }
            ul {
                display:none;
            }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
       <h2>Guided Tours</h2>
            <hr>
            <div id="tours" class="card">
                <!-- click to show -->
                <button type="button" value="Show Offers" class="btn showOffers btn-primary btn-sm">Show Offers</button>
                
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush offer">
                <li class="usa tour newOffer list-group-item"; data-name="New York" data-price="550">
                  <h3>New York, USA</h3>
                    
                    <span class="details badge badge-success">$<span id="numberPriceOffer">1,899</span> for 
                    <span id="numberNightsOffer">7</span> nights</span>
                    
                  <button class="book btn btn-primary">Book Now</button>
                </li>

                <li class="europe tour newOffer list-group-item" data-name="Paris" data-price="450">
                  <h3>Paris, France</h3>
                    <span class="details badge badge-success">$<span id="numberPriceOffer">2,299</span> for 
                    <span id="numberNightsOffer">7</span> nights</span>
                    
                  <button class="book btn btn-primary">Book Now</button>
                </li>

                <li class="asia tour popular list-group-item" data-name="Tokyo" data-price="650">
                  <h3>Tokyo, Japan</h3>
                  <span class="details badge badge-success">$<span id="numberPriceOffer">3,799</span> for 
                    <span id="numberNightsOffer">7</span> nights</span>
                  <button class="book btn btn-primary">Book Now</button>
                </li>
              </ul>
                <ul id="buttons" class="list-group list list-group-flush">
                <button class="filterNew btn btn-info">New</button>
                <button class="filterPopular btn btn-info">Popular</button>
                </ul>
            </div>
        
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Number of nights</label>
                <input type="nights" class="numberNights form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter a number">
                
              </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>
            </form> 
        </div>





        <!-- Scripts -->

        <!-- Jquery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="guidedtours.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Looking into the second problem what do you mean by after then it must appear in right section

Comment: I try do this by each(), but it doesn't work:

 `// input for number nights
    $('.numberNights').on('keyup', function() {
       var numberNights = +$(this).val(); 
       var priceOffer = +$('li').closest('.tour').data('price');
        
       // $('#numberPriceOffer').text(numberNights * priceOffer);
        $('#numberPriceOffer').each(function(index){
            $(index).text(index + $(this).text(numberNights * priceOffer));
        })`

Comment: it's working on my snippet check it. You might be missing something. See the // input for number nights section in js code.

Comment: I see, you added just `$('.offer').find('li').each(function()` to jQuery and class `.offer` to Html, and it worked. Nice solution. Do you have some idea for second case?

Comment: I am not getting what exactly you want for second case

Comment: I want to replace keyup for enter event, so that I need to press enter to get the result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157292/discussion-between-sanchit-patiyal-and-adam).